# Reddit API returns 401 (using OAuthSwift)

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, authorization, reddit

So i am trying get my sample reddit app working with OAuthSwift

I am getting `401` and `Unauthorized` from reddit

```
oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
     consumerKey:    "reddit_Client_id",
     consumerSecret: "",
     authorizeUrl:   "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize",
     accessTokenUrl: "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",
     responseType:   "code"
)
    
guard let rwURL = URL(string: "redditTestApp://oauth-callback") else { return }
    
handle = oauthswift!.authorize(
        withCallbackURL: rwURL,
        scope: "identity read", state:"reddit") { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let (credential, response, parameters)):
          print(credential.oauthToken)
          // Do your request
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.description)
        }
}
```

I am kinda lost on what i am missing here. I think i have passed all the parameters and not sure what is left for the reason to get an `unauthorized` response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So leaving it here just in case somebody in future needs help.

The problem was that during retrieving the access token reddit requires an authorization header with http basic auth.

The OAuthSwift library provides an easy way to do this you just need to add

`oauthswift?.accessTokenBasicAuthentification = true`

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! I was loosing my mind with the same problem, in addition to that line

```
oauth.accessTokenBasicAuthentification = true
```

before authorize(withCallbackURL..., you also need to add your client_id as user and empty string as password to the authorize parameters

```
oauthswift.authorize(withCallbackURL: redirectURL,
                     scope: "identity read",
                     state: "reddit",
                     parameters: ["user": "your_key", "password": "", "duration": "permanent or temporary", "grant_type": "authorization_code"])
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.